# Vue Template ref TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'scrollHeight')

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, typeerror

I am attempting to make a responsive sidebar in Vue and when I refactored my project to remove the state.js file my dropdown/collapse elements I give this `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'scrollHeight')` that I am not sure how to solve.

I've read that

> this error occurs when the scrollHeight property is accessed on an
> undefined value. To solve the error, make sure to only access the
> scrollHeight property on valid HTML elements.

But I am using a template ref here to grab the element, so I'm not sure why it wouldn't be accessable. Also, I had this working before I did my refactor and I just cannot figure out a way to work through this error.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers!

[**Codesandbox Build**](https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-sidemenu-lnwr63?file=/src/components/MyAccountDropdown.vue)

**LangDropdown.vue** (both dropdowns use the same `update` event where the error occurs)

```
<template>
  <div class="_custom-select" @blur="dropdownIsOpen = false">
    <div class="_custom-select-inner" @click="dropdownIsOpen = !dropdownIsOpen">
      <div style="display: flex">
        <!-- <img style="width: 34px" class="_icon" src="../assets/languages-icon.svg" alt="Change Language Icon" /> -->
        <div style="width: 34px" class="_icon">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 34 34">
          <defs>
            <clipPath id="clip-path">
              <rect id="Rectangle_2210" data-name="Rectangle 2210" width="34" height="34" rx="5" transform="translate(-7 -5)" fill="#fff"/>
            </clipPath>
          </defs>
          <g id="languageIcon" transform="translate(7 5)">
            <g id="Group_2048" data-name="Group 2048" clip-path="url(#clip-path)">
              <path id="Path_3921" data-name="Path 3921" d="M7.267,10A17.388,17.388,0,0,0,9.89,4.15H1.142a1.042,1.042,0,1,1-.056-2.08c.449-.009.9,0,1.348,0h3.8c0-.339,0-.665,0-.992A1.01,1.01,0,0,1,6.625.231.987.987,0,0,1,7.678.091a.936.936,0,0,1,.61.845c.02.365,0,.732,0,1.132h.234q2.429,0,4.859,0a1.068,1.068,0,0,1,1.09.72,1.035,1.035,0,0,1-.98,1.36c-.247.007-.493,0-.74,0h-.736a19.4,19.4,0,0,1-3.413,7.545c.17.19.338.375.5.564a1.007,1.007,0,0,1,.2,1.094A.986.986,0,0,1,8.432,14a1.009,1.009,0,0,1-.861-.354c-.094-.1-.186-.206-.292-.323-.1.109-.2.215-.3.319a20.039,20.039,0,0,1-5.393,3.981,1.044,1.044,0,0,1-1.521-.531,1,1,0,0,1,.41-1.213c.467-.289.96-.536,1.432-.818a17.068,17.068,0,0,0,3.911-3.22.186.186,0,0,0,.012-.286,20.012,20.012,0,0,1-2.169-3.8,1.06,1.06,0,0,1,.25-1.277,1,1,0,0,1,1.32-.01,1.467,1.467,0,0,1,.356.5A19.431,19.431,0,0,0,7,9.613c.079.121.163.239.265.39" transform="translate(0 0)" fill="#fff"/>
              <path id="Subtraction_34" data-name="Subtraction 34" d="M1.045,12.441a1.017,1.017,0,0,1-.365-.068,1.148,1.148,0,0,1-.343-.208A1.016,1.016,0,0,1,0,11.327a.925.925,0,0,1,.079-.306c.166-.364.349-.728.527-1.079v0l.166-.33c1.338-2.674,2.8-5.6,4.472-8.934a1.335,1.335,0,0,1,.4-.508A.875.875,0,0,1,5.907.041,1.012,1.012,0,0,1,6.2,0a1.4,1.4,0,0,1,.2.015A.965.965,0,0,1,6.67.094a.923.923,0,0,1,.217.142A1.372,1.372,0,0,1,7.2.668C7.8,1.858,8.42,3.1,8.968,4.194l.017.034L9.607,5.47l.6,1.192.021.042c.673,1.344,1.37,2.735,2.052,4.11a2.577,2.577,0,0,1,.147.407h0c.019.063.039.129.06.192a1.237,1.237,0,0,1-.234.611,1.033,1.033,0,0,1-.223.218,1.015,1.015,0,0,1-.285.142,1.123,1.123,0,0,1-.339.053,1,1,0,0,1-.458-.109,1.02,1.02,0,0,1-.364-.317,1.9,1.9,0,0,1-.154-.261L10.3,11.5c-.333-.662-.678-1.347-1.01-2.025a.275.275,0,0,0-.1-.124.3.3,0,0,0-.155-.033h0l-2.729,0c-1.025,0-1.97,0-2.888,0h0a.288.288,0,0,0-.164.04.314.314,0,0,0-.1.131c-.394.8-.78,1.584-1.178,2.356a1.192,1.192,0,0,1-.177.256,1.06,1.06,0,0,1-.222.186A.991.991,0,0,1,1.045,12.441ZM6.223,3.349,5.267,5.262l-.081.162-.208.416-.7,1.407h3.9L7.457,5.818l-.215-.431L6.223,3.349Z" transform="translate(8.305 8.31)" fill="#fff"/>
            </g>
          </g>
        </svg>
        </div>
        <div style="flex: 1; display: flex; justify-content: space-between">
          <div v-if="!collapsed" class="_selected-option">
            <div>
              {{ selected }}
            </div>
            <!-- <img class="_icon" src="../assets/chevron-down.svg" alt="" /> -->
             <div class="_icon">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-chevron-down"><polyline points="6 9 12 15 18 9"></polyline></svg>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
        <ul class="_options" ref="bodyEl" :style="bodyStyle">
          <li v-for="(option, i) of options" :key="i" @click="selectOption(option)">
            {{ option }}
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent, ref, watchEffect, onMounted, onBeforeUnmount } from "vue"

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
      options: { type: Array, required: true },
      default: { type: String, required: true },
      collapsed: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    },
  emits: 'input',
  setup(props, context){
    const selected = ref(props.default ? props.default : props.options.length > 0 ? props.options[0] : null)
    const dropdownIsOpen = ref(true)
    if (props.collapsed) dropdownIsOpen.value = false
    const bodyEl = ref(null)
    const bodyStyle = ref({})
    const update = () => bodyStyle.value = {
      maxHeight: `${dropdownIsOpen.value ? bodyEl.value.scrollHeight : 0}px`
    }
    watchEffect(update)
    onMounted(()=> window.addEventListener('resize', update))
    onBeforeUnmount(()=> window.removeEventListener('resize', update))
    function selectOption(_option) {
      selected.value = _option
      dropdownIsOpen.value = false
      context.emit("input", _option)
    }
    return {
      selectOption, 
      selected,
      dropdownIsOpen,
      bodyEl,
      bodyStyle
    }
  }
});

</script>

<style lang="sass">
._custom-select
  position: relative
  width: 100%
  text-align: left
  outline: none
  font-size: 16px
  border-radius: 6px
  margin-bottom: 2em
  &:hover
    ._icon,
    ._selected-option
      background-color: var(--sidebar-item-hover)
._custom-select-inner
  display: flex
  flex-direction: column
  justify-content: space-between
._selected-option
  flex: 1
  display: flex
  justify-content: space-between
  margin-left: 1em
  text-align: left
  border-radius: 6px
  padding: 8px 18px
  cursor: pointer
  user-select: none
  line-height: 26px
._icon
  width: 24px
  border-radius: 6px
  cursor: pointer
._options
  overflow: hidden
  max-height: 0
  padding: 0 1rem
  transition: max-height .3s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1)
  margin-left: auto
  list-style-type: none
  > *
    border-radius: 6px
    text-align: left
    cursor: pointer
    user-select: none
    padding: 6px
    width: 100%
  > *:hover
    background-color: var( --sidebar-item-hover)

._custom-select ._options div:hover
  background-color: var( --sidebar-item-hover)
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`watchEffect` call the `update` function before the DOM has been mounted, so `bodyEl` will still be null in this case.

You can use the `watch` method instead, and you can call `update` method on `onMounted` lifecycle.

I update the code, please check.

https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-sidemenu-forked-pukubl